How to tell android-studio to remember the size of quick documentation window which pops-up on hover?
The problem is very clear, I just want the quick documentation pop-up window to be as wide as I set it and doesn't revert back to default.
I am running Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 on macOS Sequoia 15.0
I have already checked the Remember size for each tool window in Appearance settings but it is active only for static windows like Terminal or Logcat not the pop-up windows
Here is how it looks.
